# Package Pygame Is Not detected by pycharm

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm

I installed pygame by using the following command-

```
pip install pygame
```

But when I tried to import pygame in a project on pycharm it shows me error that the module pygame is not found. But it works fine in Python IDLE. Please help me and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to install the pygame package.

1. Go to File
2. Settings
3. Go to Python Interpreter
4. Click on the plus icon and search for pygame
5. Select pygame and click 'install package'.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: No probs! Please accept the answer if this solved your issue.

Comment: Please if u can vote this question .

Comment: If the answer helped you - please mark it as accepted. This has nothing to do with me upvoting your question. Frankly, I don't think your question was well researched as a simple google search would have solved your question quicker than you posting on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Just click on `pygame` where you imported it, pycharm will show you a red bulb icon click on that red icon you will get these option and install from here.

[image: pycharm installation option]